# Is it necessary to have atomic flags in multi-threaded code?

Tags: multithreading

I was wondering if it is really necessary to have atomic flags in a multi-threaded code. For this problem, I focus on a common situation in multi-thread code: stopping threads by setting a flag.

Let's assume following pseudo-code:

```
is_running = 1;
create_threads(stopper_thread, running_thread_A, running_thread_B, running_thread_C);


stopper_thread         running_thread_A        running_thread_B        running_thread_C
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 if (x)             |  while(is_running) {   | while(is_running) {   | while(is_running) {
    is_running = 0; |  }                     | }                     | }
```

In this pseudo-code, all `running_thread_x` threads use common variable `is_running` to check if they are running or not. When we want to stop them in `stopper_thread`, we just set `is_running` to `0`. this means that `is_running` is a shared resource between threads. In a lot of coding samples, people use atomic variables (for example `std::atomic_flag` in C++) for `is_running` flag or access to this variable in a critical section to provide mutual exclusion in accessing this variable.

*But is synchronizing this flag necessary?*

I somehow believe that in situations similar to aforementioned example where there is just *stopping operation* as single or multi **stopper** thread(s), it is practically not necessary to synchronize access to this flag.

*Why?*

Because as far as I know, even if we have simultaneous access to `is_running` flag in multiple threads when we want to stop threads, this access **does not prevent from setting this flag from `1` to `0` by stopper thread**. What happens is that this change may not be reflected in running threads immediately. But is this important? I think not, because if we don't read value `0` from `is_running` in current iteration of running threads, you will finally read it after few more iterations and thread will be stopped finally. So setting this flag will finally stops all running threads, but stopping may be delayed a little.

What do you think about my argument? Is my argument correct? or I may be missing a situation that my argument fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happens is that this change may not be reflected in running threads immediately.

What happens is that this is an **undefined behaviour**. The compiler is allowed to do pretty much anything with non-synchronized code. For example it is allowed to rewrite

```
while(is_running) { }
```

into

```
auto running = is_running;
while(running) { }
```

when condition doesn't change inside while body.

And so it will loop forever, regardless of future values of `is_running`. This rewrite is not allowed when `is_running` is declared as atomic.

Moreover without atomic even if the compiler doesn't rewrite this code, the CPU is still allowed to do it (it may read the stale value from cache, not memory).

The reason people use atomics is to avoid UB. If you do multi threading then you **have to** use synchronization primitives whenever you synchronize threads. There's no escape.

Comment: I think compiler cannot rewrite code as you mentioned, because standard (at least in C++ ) states that: *This expression is evaluated before each iteration*. So that conversion is not valid, because it does not evaluate in each iteration. I think it should similar in other languages too. **volatile** has some effect in some conditions, but not sure about atomic in compiler level. But I'm not sure in CPU level.

Comment: @Afshin I'm not sure about the standard (your quote **does not** mean such rewriting is not allowed), I'm too lazy to check, but compilers most definitely do such things: https://godbolt.org/z/PmKC3U under -O3.

Comment: @Afshin https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model "If a data race occurs, the behavior of the program is undefined." And you have a data race.

Comment: yea,I noticed this one. in case you your code sample, I think that happened because your code was optimized because it was simple. check here: https://godbolt.org/z/2TyFNN in this case conditioned is check every time.

Comment: @Afshin well, as I said: the compiler **is allowed** to do this. I'm not saying it does it every time. And I'm not going to think whether it will happen in my case or not and why. Just use atomics (or other synchronization primitives) and be sure that your code has a well defined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

When `std::mutex`/`pthread_mutex_t` and `std::condition_variable`/`pthread_cond_t` are used to communicate with the thread the flag shouldn't be atomic because it must be stored to and loaded from only when the mutex is locked. Trying to use `std::atomic`/`atomic_flag`/`atomic_bool` for the flag to bypass mutex locking leads to a deadlock.

E.g.:

```
+-----+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|Step |Thread A                        |Thread B                        |
+-----+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|1    |                                |lock the mutex                  |
+-----+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|2    |                                |check whether the flag is not   |
|     |                                |set or the queue is empty       |
+-----+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|3    |set the atomic flag             |                                |
+-----+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|4    |notify condition variable       |<notification is lost>          |
+-----+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|5    |                                |and if so wait on the condition |
|     |                                |variable.                       |
+-----+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

In this scenario thread A can do steps 3 and 4 after B did step 2 but before it has done step 5. In this case the condition variable notification from step 4 is lost leading thread B to wait on the condition variable in step 5 forever.

Comment: interesting situation, but why will happen with non-atomic flag? thread B may still read correct value of flag before waiting on CV. :) in addition, in my question I did not use *any* synchronization method and I was wondering if my situation can lead to undesired behavior.

Comment: @Afshin With non-atomic flag thread A has to lock the mutex first and the deadlock can no longer happen because both store and load of the flag happen when the mutex is locked.